# Variables as commands

Tags: java, variables, calculator, arithmetic-expressions

I want to be able to use a set of variables that can stand in for mathematical operators. I am attempting to create a calculator as a learning exercise. I figure it would not be good to have the calculation occur every time a button is pressed, so how do I change the operators in a question without containing the calculations in an if statement?

### Example

```
string plus = +;
string equals = =;
public void button_clicked(....)
{
    .....
    7 equals 4 plus 3;
```

Comment: It is not a learning exercise if you ask others to do it for you (and to read your mind w.r.t. what you want first).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.  What do you mean by "change the operators in a question".  What is the question?

Comment: Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree and this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation

Comment: Your answer is in your title: Command Pattern!

Comment: I'd side-step all this by using the `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the result of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

First question. Why would it not be good to calculate when the button is pressed, much simpler.

If you really want you can use a command pattern and store a list of commands to execute when the user clicks equals.

E.g.

```
public interface Operation {

    public double execute();

}

public class Add implements Operation {

    private double num1;
    private double num2;

    public Add(double num1, double num2) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    public double execute() {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

}
```

Then each time a button is peressed, you create a new operation and store in list. When equals is pressed you execute each operation passing the result from one to the next.

You will obviously need many more operations.